# How should I understand 集合?

Tags: translation

I looked up the definition for 集合 in Baidu but I'm not sure how to use it. My example is like this:

> 其博大宽泛的特性集合，～

The context of this sentence is that it's describing PHP, a popular programming language. My translation thus far might look like this: `Its ubiquity ...`, with ubiquity being my translation for `博大宽泛` (i.e. widespreadness, popularity, etc.). I don't understand how 集合 works here. The definition I have for 集合 is 'assembled', 'set', 'brought together'.

The full passage is like this. It's technical, but I don't need help translating the technical part of it, just help understanding the grammatical aspect:

> 其博大宽泛的特性集合，简捷友好的语法结构以及对不同操作系统和Web服务器的支持，已经使它称为～

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure `博大宽泛` is referring to its ubiquity and not its broad generality? If the latter, then it could be saying that being a kitchen-sink language has led to its success or something. I don't feel confident enough to make an answer though.

Comment: Maybe… it's just not clear to me how to translate the first phrase.

Comment: Your understanding of 集合 is correct. The E-book was written in English, but subsequently translated to Chinese. Some parts of it may sound unnatural to a Chinese reader because it was translated word for word. The original text reads something like this "PHP is the engine behind millions of dynamic web applications. Its broad feature set, approachable syntax, and support for different operating systems and web servers...". The best way to learn Chinese is still to read text that is written originally in Chinese.

Comment: @QuestionOverflow If you make your comment into an answer I'll mark it as the right answer. :)

Comment: 博大宽泛 here means **all-encompassing**. So the first part of this sentence could be translated into *its all-encompassing/universal feature set*. Ubiquity makes no sense here. Ubiquitous means *found everywhere simultaneously*, which doesn't fit into the context of this sentence.

Comment: It usually means "a set of" or "a collection of"

Answer (score 3):

‘集合’ refers to **set** when it comes to math.

‘集合’ refers to **a collection/bunch of** when it comes to your sentence, which means a bounch of features.

Comment: Welcome to Chinese Language and Usage Beta! Hello ChouLin. Usually we prefer longer and more elaborated answers on short answers. If you can improve your answer by adding detail, context, examples, and backing up with references, this would increase your answer's quality. Poor answers risk being down-voted and subsequently removed.

Comment: Include some explanations, it will only help your answer to be better and you'll get more votes too! :)